# NSIS scripts that creates 32bit installer and sysnative

Tags: filesystems, 32bit-64bit, nsis, system32

I did a script to make an installer for a **64bits driver**, so it needs to place the .dll in the real **system32**.

So, I uses **sysnative** that is suppose to jump the redirector.

but tried it in Win7 64bits, and all that it does is to **create a folder at\named c:\Windows\Sysnative** and actually placing the .dll here!. **What is wrong?**.

```
delete "$WINDIR\sysnative\flulpypt64.dll"


CopyFiles   "$INSTDIR\flulpypt64.dll" "$WINDIR\sysnative\flulpypt64.dll"
```

the other solution, exists a way to tell NSIS to compile 64bits .exe installer?.

Answer (score 0):

Sysnative does not exist on WinXP-64. If you take a look in `x64.nsh` you will find some macros that turn off filesystem redirection, you can then extract the file directly to the real system directory...